# Giving unsigned char** a value in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, char, buffer

I'm really rusty with C++ and pointers and can't figure out a solution to my problem.

Here is the context:

I have to write a DLL to replace an old one and for one of the functions i must follow this signature:

```
int GetText(unsigned char** outBuf, unsigned int* outLen);
```

In the final piece of software, the value of outBuf is displayed in a textbox.

If i understand correctly, outBuf is a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer to char array.
outLen seems to be the length of the data i provide to this buffer.

To test out this function, i'd like to create from scratch a char array and pass it to outBuf.

What i tried so far:

```
int GetText(unsigned char** outBuf, unsigned int* outLen){  
*outBuf = NULL;
*outLen = 0;

//Create a char array from scratch, just to test...
unsigned char text[] = "Hello";

//outLen is the size of text
*outLen = sizeof(text);

//I allocate size to outBuf
*outBuf = new unsigned char[*outLen];

//I copy value of text into outBuf
memcpy(*outBuf, &text, *outLen);
    
return OK;
```

};

Is my code to give value to *outBuf and *outLen correct and what could lead it to not working? Because when i try it with the piece of software i was given to test the dll, it fails. It displays a dialog saying Reading failed with status 0.
The function seems to go through as the return value(status) is taken in account. But it doesn't manage to display anything. As if one of the variables i return is empty or null...

here is an extract from the final software (in VB) calling the function. As i'm not allowed to disclose the real code, i changed some value callings:

```
'lance la lecture
StatusInt = LectureText(NumText, textStr
If StatusInt = 0 Then
    'traitement des sauts de ligne
    textStr= Replace(textStr, Chr(&HD) + Chr(&HA), Chr(&HA))
    textStr= Replace(textStr, Chr(&HA), Chr(&HD) + Chr(&HA))
    
    'copie dans la textbox
    Text1.Text = textStr
Else
    MsgBox "Lecture failed with err " & Str(StatusInt)
End If
```

And the function

```
Public Function LectureText(ByVal NumText, ByRef Text As String) As Long
Dim AddrText As Long
'Dim TextAs String
Dim LengthText As Long
Dim status As Long

'lecture du text
status = GetText(AddrText, LengthText)

'si lecture ok, copie et lib�re le buffer
If status = 0 And LengthText <> 0 Then
    'Alloue l'espace n�cessaire pour le text
    Text = String(LengthText, vbNullChar)
    
    'copie du text
    CopyMemory ByVal Text, ByVal AddrText, LengthText
End If

'retourne status
LectureText= status
```

End Function

As you can see, if you provide a status = 0, it should not call the dialog saying there is an error. But in my case, it says "Lecture failed with err 0". How is it even possible...

i'm sure it's not the correct way to make things but i don't usually work with C++ and need to spend as little time as possible on this problem. I already searched for 2 days would need to take many things back from the start about C++. Thing i can't offer now.

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: `sizeof` will work, with the code as written, but `strlen` (use `strlen(text) + 1`, to account for the terminating `nul`) is less fragile.  However, OP, you need to know what the function you plan to replace actually *does*.  In particular, does it allocate memory with `new` or `malloc`?  You will need to know this when the time comes to free it.

Comment: OP, if your only question is _"Am I correct?"_ the best answer is probably "That's a reasonable guess, if you don't have documentation describing the purpose of those parameters.  But it's only a guess."

Comment: `//I allocate size to outBuf` -- So who gets to delete this memory?  And how?  Consider that you may be creating a memory leak.

Comment: @DrewDormann The purpose of those parameters are to display a text in a textbox when user click on a button to retrieve the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes i know about memory leaks but it's just not what i care the most about for now. For now, i'd like to replace the old function by the new one  and check it's working. Thanks

Comment: @PaulSanders The original function ask for a text an display it in a textbox.

Comment: @momone50 Am I correct that your question here is _"Am I correct?"_

Comment: @momone50 -- *but it's just not what i care the most about for now* -- The issue with looking at the problem this way is that once you do get to addressing the possible memory leakage, that function you wrote may have to change, and drastically.

Comment: @DrewDormann No the final question is not 'am i correct'. Was just asking that on a part of my assumptions.
The real question is what is wrong in my code, and what is leading it to not working.

Comment: @momone50 you may want to [edit] your post so that the one question in the post is really the question you are seeking an answer to.  Currently "Am I correct?" is the only question you have asked, and there is no mention of whether this code works or how _specifically_ it might be misbehaving.

Comment: @DrewDormann Just edited my original question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: What is "not working"?  You need to be specific

Comment: @Paul Sanders I edited my original post.

Comment: Outside of quibbles that could be important in the bigger picture, your posted sample code appears properly functional. It's time to take closer look at the calling code to check out its expectations.

Comment: @momone50 your function is _correct_, for some definition of "correct".  It does something, and does it without error.  You seem to be saying that what it does is not what the rest of your program expects it to do.  So the _real question_ implied here is "What does the rest of my program expect this function to do?"  I'm not sure we have any way of answering that.

Comment: Please show the code calling this function

Comment: @DrewDormann The fact is i'm not allowed to disclose any piece of code except what i already posted. Maybe i should think about what other thing could a software with such a function? Appart from from what i assumed until now...

Comment: I edited original post adding calling functions in the final piece of software. Please note that it is not the "real" code as i'm not allowed to disclose it. I modified some variables, functions and values names. Hope i didn't do a mistake while modifying this.

Comment: What is the size of your VB Long and what is the size of your C++ pointer? There could be a mismatch there.

Comment: @AviBerger Where should i check to know that? What VB long are you talking about? Thanks for the lead

Comment: What VB Long: `Dim AddrText As Long` [According to this page, a VB Long is 8 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type), but I don't believe it has always been that & don't want to assume what version of VB you are using. Check out the docs for your version. For C++, check on the value of 'sizeof(char*)'. It is likely 4 bytes for a 32 bit build and 8 bytes for a 64 bit build.

Comment: As a different issue, you will have to address the issue of memory leaks eventually.

Comment: @AviBerger as i can't modify the VB part, what would be the correction to make in my DLL function to stick to the 8 bytes long (Assuming VB longs are 8 bytes)?

Comment: My Dll function returns a status = 0. So it should never call the part displaying the Error Dialog... I edited my post regarding this...

Comment: **First find out what your situation actually is.** If there is no discrepancy, then this isn't the issue. If the VB side is 8 byte longs and is a 64 bit build then C++ side should be 8 byte pointers and a 64 bit build and not the problem. In other cases - well what case?

Comment: @AviBerger My Dll is built to replace a X86 dll. So i configured it this way. And so i assume the VB program is built for x86

Comment: [This page indicates VB Long went from 4 to 8 bytes between v. 6 and 7](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Data_Types). That was a breaking change and implies the VB side is being largely rewritten & can and is being changed by someone. If this is the situation _and you are committed to 32 bit builds_ (x86) then the answer is probably for someone to change the VB side to use Integer rather than Long (though test it first). **However,** a change to x64 seems likely, in which case this wouldn't be needed or appropriate. In other situations - who knows?

Comment: @AviBerger The dll i'm writing is acting as a bridge between the VB software and a specific Serial Terminal. The VB side is not intended to be changed and no new versions will be compiled. Rewriting the dll is just to bridge to another brand of Terminal without the need to change the VB side. Just by substituting one dll for the other

Answer (score 2):

The code i wrote was correct.
The fact is my functions needed to be declared with __stdcall to be compatible with VB.
But when compiling the dll with __stdcall, Visual Studio was adding decoration to function names and the existing software in VB was trying to call them by their undecorated names.
So i added a definition file (.def) to my project so that the function names are exported correctly.